# I have vectors of ones and zeroes. How can I efficiently determine if one vector is covered by another vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, processing-efficiency

I was having trouble fitting my question into the 150 character limit of the title; I apologize if it's unclear.

Let's say I have two vectors of equal length (A and B) composed entirely of ones and zeroes.  I'd like to know if there exists any pair A_i and B_i such that A_i = 0 when B_i = 1.

My problem is efficiency.  It's trivially easy to write a for-loop, do an element by element comparison, set a flag and break if the condition is met.  The problem comes up though, that I'm working on matrices of up to 20000 rows and numbers of columns of a similar magnitude.  I'd like to have a way of quickly doing this check and removing any of the rows which are redundant for my purposes... at this scale the element by element comparison takes an impractical amount of time.

Is there any elegant linear algebra trick to address this in an efficient way?

Edit 1:  The columns aren't exactly arranged at random.  I can't say that they are strictly sorted, but I can say that as I go from left to right the columns on the left are more likely to cover columns the left than vice-versa (by cover, I mean that A covers B iff for all i, if A_i = 1 then B_i = 1 too).  I can try and apply some additional kind of sorting to them if it would make addressing the problem easier (but I would prefer to avoid that if the sorting process would be similarly impractical).

Within individual columns, I'm not aware of any pattern to how the ones are distributed by index.

Comment: Is there anything else known about the sets? Are they sorted?

Comment: Sort of... I'll add a little on that in the main post.

Comment: in any programming language at some point, all matrices operations are loop based.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to do.  What is this "covering" relation supposed to be?  You say that A_i = 0 when B_i = 1.  Is that for a single i or every i in the row?

Comment: If the vectors are at a size of int/long/etc you can conveniently use xor and check that the result is > 0. Both actions are pretty efficient. Other than that you should look for tools that might support such actions such as MATLAB, MATHEMATICA etc.

Comment: Okay, I see the edit.  And what kind of information are you trying to get from the query you want to write?  Just a boolean representing "there exists a pair (A,B) such that B covers A" or a list of pairs or what?